# Edit style don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am trying to edit a "margin-top" property in javascript.
The following code snippets work in my Safari 6.1.6 but not in my Safari 10.1

```
document.getElementById("fbContent").setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 70px!important");
document.getElementById("fbContent").style.cssText = "margin-top: 70px!important";
document.getElementById("fbContent").style.setProperty("margin-top","70px","important");
```

Any suggestions how to solve this? 
p.s. if there is the possibility i don't want to use jquery!
thanks :)

Update: thanks for the current solution but the only browser these solutions work is the old safari(6.1.6)

Comment: The property is in a file defined which i cant edit. Dont't ask its horrible to work with. I have no other possibility...

Comment: From answers below. If you need to set it important it means that you've got another style already for #fbContent?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: I have a CSS only solution for you. Is there a reason you want a JS solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
document.getElementById("fbContent").style.marginTop = "70px";
```

```html
<div id='fbContent'>fbContent</div>
```

You can put CSS into the page using JavaScript:

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
    styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
  styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

addNewStyle('#fbContent {width:70px !important;}')
```

This method will add a `style` tag to the bottom of the `head` element which will overwrite any previous `style` tags. This is why this works.

The reason the other 'simple' option doesn't work is purely because javascript doesn't support it.

Comment: thans :) but it have to be !important

Comment: Updated my answer @Erdnuss

Comment: Have you changed `fbContent` to `#fbContent` in the `addNewStyle`?

Comment: @Erdnuss - check my comment above.

Comment: hell jeah :D how could i overlook this damm #. Yes your solution works. Thank you! your safed my day :D

Comment: but there is one thing i am interested in. Do you have an explanation why only this works and not the simple solution with getting the element and change the style? :)

Comment: tanks, i really appreciate your engagement! The world need more people like you

Comment: Absolutely no worries! :) I'm just happy to help :) @Erdnuss

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the css property directly and not via `setProperty` method.

```
document.getElementById("fbContent").style.marginTop = "70px"
```

Comment: Using `!important` wont actually work and will fail to have a margin at all.

Comment: improved my answer!

Comment: sorry but it have to be !important, so it don't work

Comment: is there another way to use this and adding !important?

Answer (score 1):

CSS Only Solution

https://jsfiddle.net/99b85ymb/3/

```
#fbContent {margin: 'whateverItIs'}
body #fbContent {margin-top: 70px;}

<div id="one">
   <div id="fbContent"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: in my fiddle I only targeted the background color to show it works.
EDIT2: made it simpler. You only need to edit the CSS now.

Comment: This is not what he asked for.

Comment: @johannesp He wants to add margin top to that element. If it absolutely needs to be dynamic, then sure, use javascript. My solution is CSS only. He also only said no jQuery.

Comment: after reading it again I think he has the problem, that he can not access the css-files and wants to 'hack' the margin into it...

Comment: 'hack' The one thing no developer wants to do but have done at least once in their career. Either way he has two working answers to choose from :)

Comment: yes thats right. I have to do a 'hack' solution. so the only CSS solution don't work, of cours i have tried but thank you

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing answers to do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("fbContent").style.marginTop = "70px";
```

sure this works, but it's a better way to split CSS and JS strictly. In order to achieve this I would advise to define a CSS class and add it with your Javascript.

CSS:

```
.marginTop { margin-top : 70px !important; }
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('fbContent').class += ' marginTop';
```

Or with Jquery:

```
$('#fbContent').addClass('marginTop');
```

Comment: i'll give this a try

Comment: worked on my old Safari, but again not on the new one... anyway thanks